# user get notification when postgresql database updated

Tags: postgresql, triggers, notifications

I am using javaScript app and PostgreSQL database. I have car_alert as a table contains id (FK of cars table) and userid (FK of users table)

each car has  a status ( status column in cars table ).

cars

```
id | type  | status
 1 | GMC   |  stopped
 2 | Hummer|  stopped
```

users

```
userid | name 
   1   | albert
   2   | Jad
```

car_alert

```
id |  carID | userID
```

car_alert is updating and having new records (car id and userid ) every time user choose car to be alerted about.

my database information is updating every 10 min and the user should get notification message every time status for its car is changed. ( of course every user has choosed his interested cars and inserted them to the car_alert table by car id ) .

what is the best method to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to send a NOTIFY to a channel from a trigger and listen on that with the javascript.  You then have to poll in Javascript to get the async notifications (they get pushed from the db) and pass them on to the user.